# How to use a dropdown to auto fill form with data from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, autofill, dropdownbox

Hi All I have created a form below (entryform.php)to enter order details.
form contains: part_id, price, model.
I already created connect.php to connect to the database, and custompcorder.php to insert data in order_details table and entryform.php to enter data.

Here is what I will like to do on my entryform.php:
1- make the Part input field as A drop down that get part name and part_id from Parts table value to save is part_id but show part name on the entryform.
2- After the part is picked in the drop down, I want the fields price and model to be automatically filled with appropriate data from part table. Autofill will use the part_id to get the correct data. as you can see on the form below, many rows will be entered at a time.

```
  entryform.php

<?php

<form action="../action/custompcorder.php/" method="post">
<p>Part: <input type="text" name="part_id"/> Price: <input type="text" name="price"/> Model: <input type="text" name="model"/></p> 
<p>Part: <input type="text" name="part_id2"/> Price: <input type="text" name="price2"/> Model: <input type="text" name="model2"/></p> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>

?>



connect.php

<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user2';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'db3';

$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>


custompcorder.php

<?php
    include_once '../action/connect.php';

$sql="INSERT INTO order_details (part_id, price,model)
VALUES
('$_POST[part_id]','$_POST[price]','$_POST[model]'),
('$_POST[part_id2]','$_POST[price2]','$_POST[model2]')";


?>
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your input fields are text, so it doesn't make sense there. I would write a function for it, so you can simply change the query within it. As an example below here.

**Editted after questio in comments**

Have you checked with the development tools in google chrome that page? it shows you the lay-out and CSS (part 1, the mark up). and how it's build up. From there on, you can check with what functions you need to use. In your case you need a couple of dropdowns and you need to do some database work.

For instance, say you want to show the RAM memory, and you have a database called `models`, make sure you have a `partId, partPrice, partName and partType`. For instance, if you have RAM, and it's a RAM memory part, say you assign the value `1` to it. In your case your query of the dropdown would be (as I explained above)

```
function LoadRAMParts(){
    $query = "SELECT *
        FROM models
        WHERE partType = '1';
        ORDER BY partName DESC;";
    $resultaat=mysqli_query($query);
    return $resultaat;
}
```

So you get returned all your RAM Memory parts now, which you can now just simply load into your dropdown menu by using a bit of PHP

```
function MakeRAMMemoryDropDown(){  // define name of the php function and open the function
echo "<select name='RAMPartId' class='dropdown'>"; // open the dropdown with the name RAMPPartId
    $results = LoadRAMParts(); // Load in the query from earlier
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){   // while lets it loop through your results as long as there are results
    echo "<option value='".$row['partId']."'>" // the value for the ID when it's chosen
    .$row['partName']."</option>"; // the name of the product the user sees
    } // end of the loop
echo "</select>"; // end of the dropdown
} // end of the php function
```

This you exectue in a seperate file that you include on the top. (I run first my queries first, then create the dropdowns, else it becomes a conflict, because the function i call within my dropdown function has to excist, prior to the dropdown. For me it looks like this.

[image]

So as final part, and I hope i explained it to you a bit, you need to call in the function into your PHP page where you want to use it. That just goes simply by the code:

```
<?php  MakeRAMMemoryDropDown() ?>
```

As example:

[image]

And thats called dynamicly loading in your content. Now I use a different type of code placement and different ideas of generating contenct, but to each programmer it's own style. This is how I load in my content.

As for your loading prices question, you have to that with AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML) but thats not my cup of tea, I cant help you there. Sorry.

I hope I explained it to you, if not, I hope you figure it out another way then.

Comment: Thank you Dorvalla for your answer. I am pretty new in web programing and I am unable to understand your answer. 
The reason I posted my code is because I have seen too many exemple implementing part of what I want and I am not able to put them togather. I want the form to look like this:almost like this http://www.pugetsystems.com/nav/obsidian/customize.php I will use sql query on each drop down to filter what will show.

Comment: @user3383794 Updated my awnser for you.

Comment: Thank you I was able to create dropdown on many lines using Functions. Now I need help for my second question. Auto Populate the price and status field with data from Mysql after the part ID has been selected.

Comment: I can only give you a direction on which to think on this one, but not the outcome, cause technically its not what I do, or know. First of all, you need a new table in order to create your "shopping list" As you made one up there, it needs a few extra fields, including the userId (who ordered it) and you can also chose to use a sessionId (not mandatory). So what needs to happen is when somebody adds something in the shopping card, it needs to add the prices all together. You do that in a query with a SUM statement. You send this through AJAX, so you dont have to refresh the page. @user3383794

Comment: Also if you think i helped you enough, please upvote the awnser (or select it as the awnser you are looking for) I would suggest you read information about AJAX, and make some tutorials. Also I would suggest you rephrase your question or make a new question about AJAX, cause everybody now here is more about PHP than AJAX. In any case, good luck!